# pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pip, python-3.5

After I activated my Virtualenv i received this message:

> Francos-MBP:BV francoe$source bin/activate
>
> (BV) Francos-MBP:BV francoe$ pip freeze
>
> -bash: /Volumes/HD 2/Projects/PythonProjects/BV/bin/pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
>
> (BV) Francos-MBP:BV francoe$ pip install --upgrade pip -bash:
>   /Volumes/HD 2/Projects/PythonProjects/BV/bin/pip: "/Volumes/HD: bad
>   interpreter: No such file or directory

At the moment I am not able set up any virtualenv ..

[p.s. I have multiple versions of python (3.5 and systems version 2.7)]

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space in the name of your disk ("HD 2") is tripping things up.  The path to the Python interpreter (which is going to be `/Volumes/HD 2/Projects/PythonProjects/BV/bin/python`) is getting split on the space, and the system is trying to execute `/Volumes/HD`.

You'd think that in 2016 your operating system ought to be able to deal with this.  But it can't, so you need to work around it:

1. Rename "HD 2" to something that doesn't contain a space.
2. Re-create the virtualenv.

Comment: I am also having problems with this. Do you know if any update has corrected this bug? The OS (or pip, or virtualenv) should be able to escape a space, at least!